# String Pointer error while assigning a value?

Tags: c

I m trying to assign a value to string pointer.It's compiling and running but not printing the  correct answer?

```
char *x = "girl"; 
*x = x[3];
printf("%s\n",x);
```

Why it's not printing "lirl" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to change a string literal which is constant, and not possible.

```
char *x = "girl";
```

This will be stored in a section of the executable such is the `.rodata` section, and to which you cannot write.

But instead if you do:

```
char x[] = "girl";
```

or

```
char *x;
x = malloc (sizeof (char) * ENOUGH_MEMORY);
strcpy (x, "girl");
```

then you can modify the string. In the `x[] = "girl"` case the string will be stored in the function's local (or global `.data` section if `x` is global) stack, and in the `malloc` case the memory will be allocated you from the heap, and `x` stores the base address of it. In both the case you can read/write both type of locations.

Comment: That's not _exactly_ true, it all depends on the implementation

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: does the standard describes it as implementation defined behaviour ?

Comment: I don't mean it's _implementation defined_. The standard only says it's undefined. It says nothing about storing string literals in a read only memory section.

Comment: yes, but the string literal cannot be changed, that is defined, i think, therefore it is not possible to change a string literal, and yes, this can be implemented in any way.

Comment: Hence my "not _exactly_ true". I was just nitpicking.

Comment: k i will have a look at the standards have a look what it exactly tells. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot modify a string literal like that. It is undefined behavior.

You should do this instead:

```
char x[] = "girl"; 
x[0] = x[3];
printf("%s\n",x);
```

This works because `"girl"` is now an array initializer for `x[]`. Which is just a short form for:

```
char x[] = {'g', 'i', 'r', 'l', '\0'};
```

So this is allowed.

Comment: I don't understand we can initialize an integer array like           int *a[] ={1,2,3};' why not initialize char array like
   char *x[] = {'g','i','r','l'};

Comment: You can't do `int *a[] = {1,2,3};`. Get rid of the `*`. And just use: `int a[] = {1,2,3};` Same applies to the other one. (but you also need the `'\0'`) For `char[]`, it's more readable to just initialize with `"char a[] = girl"`

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying read only memory.  Don't do that.

```
char *x = "girl";
```

Should really be

```
const char *x = "girl";
```

"girl" is read only, not modifiable.  If you need to modify the string then declare x as a `char[]` and it will be allocated with automatic storage duration.

```
char x[] = "girl";
x[0] = 'c'; // legal
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression
assigns 4th (index 3) character from string to the first (index 0).
So assigning to *x is exactly assigning value to first element of string